# KL Divergence in KDE toolbox giving Inf

Tags: matlab, infinite

I am using the KDE toolbox for my work .. Here I am calculating the kde for the set of points in class 1 and set of points in class 2. Then I am taking a KLD between them --

```
        Bandwidth = 'Hall';
        p = kde(X(:,find(Y(:,1)>=0.5)),Bandwidth);
        q = kde(X(:,find(Y(:,2)>=0.5)),Bandwidth);
        divergence = kld(p,q);
```

Here X get can be nx9 vector. (n - Nine dimensional points)

For some of the cases I am getting the divergence value as 'Inf'. I am trying to figure out the cause for it. If you have any suggestions please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Link to the UCI KDE toolbox - http://www.ics.uci.edu/~ihler/code/kde.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the formula of the KL Divergence.

[image]

One reason could be that one or more of the values in the denominator must have been zero!

and `log(0) = Inf/undefined`